# Wedge product and right derived functors

Tags: commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes, derived-functors

let $f:X\to Y$ be a flat map between complex algebraic varieties and let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. Very often I've seen the following map:

$$\wedge: \bigotimes^n (R^1f_{\ast}\mathcal F)\to R^nf_\ast\left(\wedge^n \mathcal F\right)$$

> How is the map $\wedge$ formally defined? I don't understand it.

It  seems that  it is, somehow, canonically induced by the ordinary wedge product of locally free sheaves. But I don't understand why it ``commutes'' with the right derived functor $R^nf_{\ast}$.

**Edit:**
I just wanted to add that my question is by coincidence related to the following unanswered question: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345056/wedge-product-on-cohomology-groups)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give a reference?

Comment: For example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210310.pdf

pag 14, line -7 (the second arrow of the diagram). It is the localization at stalks of the map I'm talking about. They apply it for the "relative tangent sheaf".

Comment: Maybe check first what the map should do on stalks, and try to extend this definition to open subsets. For $y\in Y$ I think it looks like $\bigotimes H^1(X_y, \mathcal{F}_y)\rightarrow H^n(X_y, \wedge^n \mathcal{F}_y)$; maybe this factors through the cup product $\bigotimes H^1(X_y, \mathcal{F}_y)\rightarrow H^1(X_y, \bigotimes \mathcal{F}_y)$ and the natural map coming from the morphism $\bigotimes^n \mathcal{F}_y\rightarrow \wedge^n\mathcal{F}_y$. Probably this approach works on affine opens (not just stalks) and it probably glues to give the map globally.

Comment: I accidentally assumed $f$ was proper (e.g. if $X$ was projective) when I wrote the above comment. If this isn't the case then idea of working locally and gluing might still work but, the stalks of these sheaves could be a little different.

Comment: @Eoin Now I understand the map on stalks: as you say it is basically the cup product composed with the natural wedge product. I just wondered if there is some nice categorical construction avoiding any glueing argument.

Comment: The construction of the cup-product is purely sheaf-theoretic. In other words, it doesn't require any assumption on $f,X$ or $Y$, only on $\mathcal{F}$. Actually, even the assumption on $\mathcal{F}$ can be dropped if instead of tensor product on the right you consider the left derived tensor product.